# Why does the order of threadgroup num (work_group_launch_order) in TFLite Metal matter?

Tags: tensorflow, metal, gpu, tensorflow-lite

I'm a beginner of Metal and trying to understand the Metal implementation of convolution in **TFLite**. After having read this line of code and found all usages, I'm really confused that why the `work_group_launch_order` matters. How does this mechanism work indeed? Is it related to the way GPU linearizes the 3D `threadgroup`?

**[[Tensorflow GitHub]](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9a9a4bfec64cec8a12d31809404ece94a4f55771/tensorflow/lite/delegates/gpu/metal/kernels/conv.cc#L59)**

For simplicity, let me try to explain the thread dispatch strategy for a certain kernel (named `ConvolutionGeneric`) in TFLite.

For a given 3D thread number `t=<tx, ty, tz>` and thread group shape `s=<sx, sy, sz>`, TFLite calculates the number of desired thread groups `n=<nx, ny, nz>` by `nx=ceil(tx/sx)`, `ny=ceil(tx/sy)`, and `nz=ceil(tz/sz)`. Which is absolutely normal.

In the normal way, we can dispatch `<nx, ny, nz>` threadgroups for 3 dimensions, and acquire the thread position in grid in Metal kernel function by the argument `gid` with attribute `[[thread_position_in_grid]]`. The thread position can decide which area the current thread is responsible for.

However, TFLite chose a weird way, dispatches `<nz, nx, ny>` threadgroups for 3 dimensions, and acquire the thread position in grid in Metal kernel function by calculate from `tid3d [[thread_position_in_threadgroup]]` and `group_id [[threadgroup_position_in_grid]]` as

```
gid_x = group_id.y * sx + tid3d.x;
gid_y = group_id.z * sy + tid3d.y;
gid_z = group_id.x * sz + tid3d.z
```

What surprises me is that this strategy really has a boost on performance **(~10% speed up)**.

Can someone help me to explain the underlying mechanism behind the weird `threadgroup` dispatch strategy?